# Orthogonal smooth vector field on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Consider a compact Riemannian manifold $M$ with a smooth metric, and a smooth vector field $X$ on $M$. My question is, when can we construct another smooth vector field $Y$ on $M$ such that $Y$ is orthogonal to $X$ at all points?

Locally we are surely able to do that, but I am not sure how to (or if one can at all) do it globally (I suspect that there should be some global topological restrictions). Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Edit: The question of *existence* has been addressed in the comments below, namely, obstructions arising from characteristic classes.

I would further like to ask if there is some constructive way of getting $Y$? For example, is there some general concept of "rotating $X$ by $90^\circ$ anticlockwise (say on an orientable manifold)? Intuitively it seems to me that on a surface, this should be doable, or am I mistaken?

Comment: You cant always do this: the tangent bundle must have a trivial two dimensional distribution. There are many obstructions to this. The easiest are given by characteristic classes.

Comment: Are $Y$ (and $X$) required to be nonzero everywhere?

Comment: If vector fields are linearly independent, Gram-Schmidt makes them orthogonal, so (if you assume $X$ is nowhere zero and you want $Y$ also nowhere zero) you could really get rid of the metric and just ask when there is a vector field linearly independent of a given one. Again, this is a characteristic class question.

Comment: I recommend Milnor and Stasheff on this topic.

Comment: @BenMcKay That is excellent. I am looking through the book at the moment. I have come across some discussions on when one has $n$ linearly independent sections. Finding $2$ should be easier. If you can direct me to a specific result in the book, please let me know.

Comment: For the edit you can look at almost complex manifolds

Comment: John Wiltshire-Gordon asked a similar question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162702/how-to-flow-submanifolds . I'd like to say I don't know why people are voting to close this; it seems like a perfectly interesting question to me.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I presume this is because it's a topic routinely covered in first year grad school.  Obstruction theory gives a simple machine to answer this question on any manifold.     The Stiefel bundle of 2-frames on a manifold is non-trivial generally, but it's fiarly managable to work with.  Comparable to studying something like spin structures.

Comment: @RyanBudney No, I really don't think obstruction theory is first year graduate material. Of the "alpha" courses at Michigan, which are supposed to be more or less the first two years, include a term of algebraic topology whose syllabus you can read here https://lsa.umich.edu/content/dam/math-assets/math-document/Grad/qr-exams---math/syllabi/Algebraic%20Topology%20Syllabus%20592.pdf ; it doesn't get to obstruction theory.

Comment: Neither did the first term of graduate topology that I took as an undergrad (Harvard, first 4 chapters of Hatcher's book). I didn't take topology in grad school (Berkeley), but I helped a lot of my friends with the PSets, and I don't think it got that far either.

Comment: Sorry David, I don't know what a PSet is.  Not certain what the purpose is, of waving around our CVs.   Certainly in places that don't really specialize in topology this kind of thing would not be emphasized.  This is material that can be easily found in standard introductory textbooks.  If it's 1st year or 2nd year graduate material in one place or another, I suppose that's no big difference.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean non-vanishing tangent vector fields, as people in the comments said, there is an obstruction to doing this given by the Euler class of the quotient by the tangent bundle of $M$ by the span of $X$.  In David's example, this is the fact that he is using (the Euler class in this case is the Poincare dual of $2[S^1]$).

As also mentioned in the comments, there are some special structures that let you do this, the most obvious being an almost complex structure, which is exactly a "notion of rotating by 90 degrees." But most manifolds don't have these, in particular odd dimensional manifolds never do (some simple linear algebra shows you can't have a "notion of rotating by 90 degrees" in a consistent way on an odd dimensional manifold; think about trying to do this in 3 dimensions).

Beyond this, it's pretty unclear from your answer what you are looking for; there is, of course, no fully general construction since on many manifolds it is impossible.

Comment: To make some minor comments on vanishing vector fields: If $Y$ is allowed to be the $0$ vector field, then of course we can always succeed. If $Y$ is only allowed to vanish where $X$ does, then we can never succeed on an odd dimensional manifold: Let $X$ flow outward from a point; then a $Y$ orthogonal to $X$ near that point and not vanishing except at that point would violate the hairy ball theorem.

Answer (score 2):

I'll get things started with a simple example to see that the answer is not always yes: $S^1 \times S^2$ has a nonvanishing vector field pointing in the $S^1$ direction. But, if we had a nonvanishing vector field orthogonal to that one, its restriction to $(\text{point}) \times S^2$ would be a nonvanishing vector field on the sphere, contradicting the hairy-ball theorem.