# Sections of vector bundles with exactly one zero

Tags: vector-bundles

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/129752/21564) asking whether a connected manifold with Euler characteristic zero has a vector field without zeroes, there is the following comment by Tom Goodwillie ([see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129752/does-a-connected-manifold-with-vanishing-euler-characteristic-admit-a-nowhere-va?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment334330_129757)):

> "Two zeroes of opposite index can be taken to lie in a coordinate
>   chart (because the manifold is connected) and then they can be
>   eliminated using that fact that a map $S^{n−1}→S^{n−1}$ of degree zero
>   extends to $D^n$."

This made me think whether the following statement is true:

*For an (oriented) rank-n vector bundle over a compact connected (oriented) n-manifold there always exists a section with only one single isolated zero.*

The proof I imagine would work by succesively unifying the (finitely many) zeros of a transverse section within (contractible and hence trivializable) discs which contain two (or more) zeroes.

If the statement is actually correct, I would be particularly interested how to specify the conditions (e.g. orientability), how to construct the unification and also how one can nicely embed such unifying discs (e.g. using isotopy carrying one zero to another).

The statement would in particular imply that the bundle after removal of a point admits a non-vanishing section. In the case of an $SU(2)$-bundle over a four-manifold I could use it to prove the triviality of the bundle after removing a point (and successively the classification by the Chern number, by using a common bundle atlas with two trivialisations ((one disc and the punctured trivialisation)) and hence obtaining the Chern number by the winding number of the transition function) – all without using algebro-topological methods.

Answer (score 6):

This is true. Instead of starting with an arbitrary section and pushing all the zeroes together, you can directly construct a section with one zero.

Let $E \to M$ be a rank $n$ vector bundle over an $n$-dimensional manifold, and let $p \in M$. Set $M' = M\setminus\{p\}$.

The first obstruction to $E|_{M'} \to M'$ admitting a nowhere-zero section is the Euler class $e(E|_{M'})$ which is necessarily zero as $H^n(M'; \mathbb{Z}) = 0$. Since $\operatorname{rank} E|_{M'} = \dim M'$, this is the only obstruction, so there is a nowhere-zero section $\sigma : M' \to E|_{M'}$.

Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $M$ which has a single zero at $p$, and let $g = f|_{M'}$. Then $g\sigma$ is a nowhere-zero section of $E|_{M'}$ which extends to a section $\hat{\sigma}$ of $E$ by defining $\hat{\sigma}(p) = 0 \in E_p$.

Comment: How can one see that the Euler-Class is the only obstruction for a nowhere-zero section?

Comment: Obstruction theory: the subsequent obstructions live in higher cohomology degrees, which vanish here. The Euler class of a rank $k$ bundle should be viewed as the obstruction to have a nowhere-vanishing section on the $k$-skeleton of $M'$.

Comment: So the idea of pushing zeroes together would be a valid direct way to prove the statement?

Comment: @FelixSchlag: If you start with a transverse section and push all the zeroes together, you'll get one zero if the Euler class is non-zero, otherwise they will all cancel and you'll get a nowhere-zero section if the Euler class is zero (which is the purpose of the linked question).